# Dirac delta applied to Dirichlet function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let's denote Dirichlet function as $d(x)$:
$$d(x)=\begin{cases}{1,x \in \mathbb{Q}\\ 0,x\not\in \mathbb{Q}}\end{cases}$$
I know that Lebesgue integral of Dirichlet function on any finite domain is zero:
$$\int_a^b d(x) dx=0$$
On the other hand, integral of Dirac function is 1 on any set including $0$ ($a<0<b$):
$$\int_a^b\delta(x)dx=1$$
So, I wonder, what would this integral evaluate to:
$$\int_a^b\delta(d(x))dx$$
? Does $\delta(d(x))$ make sense at all?

Comment: I think you've got the definition of the Dirichlet function backwards. Shouldn't it be $$d(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in \mathbb Q \\ 0, & x\notin \mathbb Q\end{cases}\quad?$$

Comment: @Martin, right, fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "function" $\delta$ is in reality the measure
$$ \delta(A) = 1 \Leftrightarrow 0 \in A$$
which is not [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures) with respect to the Lebesgue measure. So the expression
$$ \delta(d(x))$$
does not have any sense, since it assumes that "function" $\delta$ is the density of the measure $\delta$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

If we interpret $\delta(x)$ as the "function" which is infinite at 0 an 0 otherwise (while integrating 1) then $\delta(d(x))$ is a "function" which is infinite at any $ x$ rational and 0 otherwise while integrating ... I think the interpretation has reached its limit.

If there is any mathematical object that could represent $\delta(d(x))$ it is a countable sum of Dirac masses (the generalization of the $\delta(x)$, which is infinite at an arbitrary point $y$, in terms of the 'function' delta that is $\delta_y(x) = \delta(x - y)$) at each rational that is
$$ ``\delta(d(x))  \text{''} = \sum_{y \in \mathbb{Q}} \delta_y $$
and so
$$ ``\int_a^b \delta(d(x)) dx \text{''} =  \sum_{y \in \mathbb{Q}} \delta_y([a,b]) = \sum_{y \in [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}} 1  = \infty$$

For $\hat{d}(x) = 1 - d(x)$ is even worse since we would have a non-countable sum of non zero terms an that is not even well-defined in general.

Comment: May I ask, why the interpretation
$$``\int_a^b \delta(d(x)) dx \text{''} =  \int_a^b d(x) d\delta(x)
$$
is natural for you?

Comment: Edited to address your question :)

Comment: Now that's something that I thought about as well. Nevertheless, I don't think there is any meaningless interpretation of $\delta(f(x))$ exactly due to the point of yours that $\delta$ is not a function.